# no puedo iniciar sesión con google (PHP)

Tags: php, session

Actualmente estoy generando un inicio de sesión por medio de redes sociales `facebook` y `google`, para ello descargué la librería de `hybridauth` y ya puedo iniciar sesión con `facebook`.

Configuré `google` y me muestra la pantalla "Selecciona una cuenta" , Mi problema es que cuando selecciono la cuenta para ingresar me dice lo siguiente:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'User
>   profile request failed! Google returned an invalid
>   response:stdClass::__set_state(array( 'error' =>
>   stdClass::__set_state(array( 'errors' => array ( 0 =>
>   stdClass::__set_state(array( 'domain' => 'usageLimits', 'reason' =>
>   'accessNotConfigured', 'message' => 'Project 803336223967 is not found
>   and cannot be used for API calls. If it is recently created, enable
>   Google+ API by visiting
>   https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/plus.googleapis.com/overview?project=803336223967
>   then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for
>   the action to propagate to our systems and retry.', 'extendedHelp' =>
>   'https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/plus.googleapis.com/overview?project=803336223967',
>   )), ), 'code' => 403, 'message' => 'Project 803336223967 is not found
>   and cannot be used for API calls.

Este es el código donde agrego las keys:

```
return

array(
    "base_url" => "http://localhost/sesioRedes/hybridauth.php",
    "providers" => array(
        "Facebook" => array(
            "enabled" => true,
            "keys" => array(
                "id" => "mi_id",
                "secret" => "secret"
            ),
            //para recuperar email
            "scope" => "email"
        ),
        "Google" => array(
            "enabled" => true,
            "keys" => array(
                "id" => "xxxx..apps.googleusercontent.com",
                "secret" => "secreto"
            )
        )
    )
)
?>
```

código del archivo `hybridauth.php` :

```
<?php

require_once ('vendor/autoload.php');

if (isset($_REQUEST['hauth_start']) || isset($_REQUEST['hauth_done'])){

    Hybrid_Endpoint::process();
}
?>
```

Ya configuré los permisos de la api, ingresé la url del callback de esta forma `localhost/sesioRedes/hybridauth.php`;, pero al dar clic en "iniciar sesión con google" me mandaba a:

> "error 400 Error: redirect_uri_mismatch" `The redirect URI in the
>   request, localhost/sesioRedes/hybridauth.php?hauth.done=Google, does
>   not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client.`

Lo que hice fue remplazar la `url` por esta: `localhost/sesioRedes/hybridauth.php?hauth.done=Google` Entonces me funcionó, pero me sigue dando el problema antes mencionado.

Answer (score 1):

**Configuraste los permisos de tu API?** puede que este enlace te ayude.
Ir a https://console.developers.google.com/ y activar el acceso de la API de Google. 
Tuve un problema similar y con esto funcionó!

Comment: Sí, configuré los permisos de la api, ingresé la url del callback de esta forma "http://localhost/sesioRedes/hybridauth.php", pero al dar clic en "iniciar sesión con google" me mandaba a: "error 400 **Error: redirect_uri_mismatch**" 

` The redirect URI in the request, http://localhost/sesioRedes/hybridauth.php?hauth.done=Google, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client. `

Lo que hice fue remplazar la url por esta: **http://localhost/sesioRedes/hybridauth.php?hauth.done=Google** 

Entonces me funcionó, pero me sigue dando el problema antes mencionado.

Answer (score 0):

Ha pasado un poco de tiempo desde la pregunta y supongo que ya estará mas que resuelto pero si algún otro llega hasta aqui visto que no hay mucha información en español os digo como lo solucioné yo.

Dentro de https://console.developers.google.com teneis que ir a activar elementos de la libreria de API y buscar contactos y google+, activando esas dos opciones os funcionará. Si habeis llegado hasta este punto la configuración está hecha pero hay un bloqueo que no deja pasar los datos del usuario

Answer (score 0):

Estaba en lo mismo, habilite contactos api y google+ api y aun me sigue respondiendo lo mismo. Si alguien tiene alguna solucion

rror: redirect_uri_mismatch

The redirect URI in the request, http://tundrainventarios.cl, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client. To update the authorized redirect URIs,